# Не получается создать массив структур. Как это сделать , если заранее размер массив не известен? Его вводит пользователь

Tags: c

Задача "Справочник"
Создать структуру со следующими полями:
Имя человека, дата рождения, профессия, стаж работы (целое число)
Логика работы программы:
При старте спрашивает сколько N записей должно быть в справочнике (человек вводит). Далее программа создает массив из структур длиной N и спрашивает у человека про каждую запись (инициализирует структуры массива).
После окончания инициализации программа спрашивает профессию, человек вводит. Программа ищет всех людей с такой профессией, считает возраст каждого и отношение его возрасту к стажу. Выводит на экран.

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 struct place{

    char name[30];
    char professional[40];
    int date;
    int worktime;
};

int main()
{   int N[];
    printf("Enter pure structures:");
    scanf("%d",&N);
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
struct place * p = malloc(N*sizeof(struct place));
```

Если компилируете как C++ (это почему-то делают сплошь и рядом...), нужен каст:

```
struct place * p = (struct place *)malloc(N*sizeof(struct place));
```

По окончании работы не забудьте

```
free(p);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Чтобы создать массив объектов динамически нужно сделать следующее:**

`NeedType* Pointer = malloc(sizeof(NeedType) * NeedElements);`

*Где NeedType = нужный тип для массива, например char*

*Где Pointer = указатель на первый элемент массива (То есть сам массив)*

*NeedElements = количество элементов*

Ещё:

malloc() в своём параметре принимает количество БАЙТ, а не элементов (На всякий случай скажу)

sizeof() в параметре нужен чтобы узнать размер одной структуры в байтах. Это работает с любым типом. (Он вернёт именно то значение, которое занимает этот тип. То есть если вы передаёте туда указатель - он вернёт размер который занимает именно указатель, а не размер того, на что он указывает.)

malloc() вернёт NULL в случае ошибки (Например если памяти не хватает для выделения)

параметр malloc() не может быть 0